# How to make query string look better in the URL with PHP?

Tags: php, query-string

Now, this is how my URL looks:

```
onlineproject/search-category-products.php?cat_id=3
```

I want to show somewhat like this:

```
onlineproject/search-category-products.php/vegetables
```

Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: If you add how is your code structured it would help a lot.

Comment: [htaccess](http://www.htaccess-guide.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Add or modify the ".htaccess" in your server so it looks like

```
Rewrite On
RewriteRule onlineproject/search-category-products.php/^(.*)$ onlineproject/search-category-products.php/?cat_id=$1 [L]
```

That way your url would look like

```
onlineproject/search-category-products.php/vegetables
```

But the request would be redirected to

```
onlineproject/search-category-products.php/?cat_id=vegetables
```

This way it looks prettier, but the mapping with the categories and their ids must be handled by the server.

Comment: thank you for the information but it gives 500 internal server error